# I can´t import packages after install with pip

Tags: python, pypi, rodeo

I am trying to install packages with pip in Rodeo in Windows with:

```
import pip

pip.main(["install","gdal"])
```

It looks like it works, as console doesn´t give back me any errors. But when I try to import the package

```
>>> import gdal as asdf
ImportError: No module named 'gdal'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-205-98f806a7d911> in <module>()
----> 1 import gdal as asdf
ImportError: No module named 'gdal'
```

It also happens with other packages. Any ideas? I think something is bad with the path... how can I tell pip where to install?

Sorry, I am new with python...

Comment: have you tried installing using `pip install <package_name>`?

Comment: You should also try `pip install wheel` if that fails

Comment: If you want `import gdal` shouldn't you install gdal?

Comment: @TheDarkKnight I have already try, it doesn´t work

Answer (score 1):

Is not clear for me what is gdal. 
You installed ggplot, does the `import ggplot` command work?

Comment: Ups! sorry, it was a copy paste error because i have tried with other packages. Edited